# Как в django сделать login через одну строчку

Tags: python, django, login

У меня есть утилита которая генерирует ключи в виде XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX.
Дальше создаётся бд по данной схеме где ключём является access_key, level это уровень доступа.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    access_key TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    level INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

как мне сделать так чтобы я мог создавать пользователя именно по этой модели через `user = User.objects.create_user()`. А также чтобы пользователь логинился через access_key.
В Django новичок, так что не судите строго

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как шаблон могу предложить такой вариант

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, access_key, level, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('The Name field must be set')
        user = self.model(name=name, access_key=access_key, level=level, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    access_key = models.CharField(max_length=19, unique=True, verbose_name='access key')
    level = models.IntegerField()

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'access_key'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'level']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Здесь создается менеджер CustomUserManager, который определяет метод create_user(), создает нового пользователя на основе данных. Модель User наследует абстрактные модели AbstractBaseUser и PermissionsMixin и определяет поля name, access_key и level

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, я так понял для этого нужно создавать startapp users, а потом как этот файл обозвать то? И в settings.py кинуть AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser", правильно понимаю?

Comment: Внутри приложения создать файл models.py и определить в нем вашу модель пользователя CustomUser.

В файле settings.py вашего проекта добавить строку AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'. Это указывает Django использовать вашу модель пользователя вместо встроенной модели User.

Затем нужно запустить миграции, чтобы создать таблицу для вашей модели пользователя в базе данных. Выполните команду python manage.py makemigrations users для создания файла миграций, а затем python manage.py migrate для применения миграций.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо большое!